# VBA Excel GetSaveAsFilename parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I am using GetSaveAsFilename command to write cells value to file. I using this, beacuse this command acquire the saving path with pop-up menu. My question is, how can I get the path, that selected the user for further using?

Here is an example

```
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=intialFilename, fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
```

This myFile will contain the new IintialFilename wtith the full path, like this:
"C:/test/t1.xlsm"

How can I get from myFile this information?

In C++/Java it would be something like this:

```
String pathThatUserGave = myFile.InitialFileName()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the string to get only the filename:

```
Sub gdjtrf()
    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=intialFilename, fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    ary = Split(myFile, "\")
    MsgBox myFile & vbCrLf & ary(UBound(ary))
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To get only the path, use:

```
Sub gdjtrf2()
    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=intialFilename, fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    ary = Split(myFile, "\")
    ary(UBound(ary)) = ""
    s = Join(ary, "\")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Discard the final slash if you do not need it.

Comment: Oh thanks, It's almost perfrect, but I want ONLY the path, without the filename. How can I do that?